# Call contact from "messaging"

Tags: sms, messaging

When I receive sms message, I want to call this contact immediately, but I have to navigate to my address book, search for contact and call it from there.

Am I missing something, is there a way to call number from messaging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

1. On the top of opened message screen tap on contact name;
2. Contact page will be opened;
3. Tap on 'call mobile'